# Navigation Menu Ghost

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, menu

I've created a website for our company, it's not done yet and a lot of content is still missing.

Currently the menu works fine on IE, but when viewed on Chrome, you get a slight ghosting of the drop down when hovered over the individual sections.

See below for code taken from Header-actions.php

```
/**
* Navigation
*
* @since 1.0
*/
function synapse_nav() {
global $options, $themeslug; //call globals 

if ($options->get($themeslug.'_hide_home_icon') == "0" && $options->get($themeslug.'_hide_search') == "0" OR $options->get($themeslug.'_hide_home_icon') == "1" && $options->get($themeslug.'_hide_search') == "0" ) {
    $grid = 'twelve columns';
}

else {
    $grid = 'nine columns';
}

?>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">

        <div class="twelve columns" id="imenu">

        <div id="nav" class="<?php echo $grid; ?>">
        <?php if ($options->get($themeslug.'_hide_home_icon') != "0"):?><div id="home"><a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() ;?>/images/home.png" alt="home" /></a></div><?php endif;?>
        <?php if ($options->get($themeslug.'_hide_home_icon') == "0"):?>
        <div id="nohome"></div>
        <?php endif;?>
        <?php wp_nav_menu( array(
        'theme_location' => 'header-menu', // Setting up the location for the main-menu, Main Navigation.
        'fallback_cb' => 'menu_fallback', //if wp_nav_menu is unavailable, WordPress displays wp_page_menu function, which displays the pages of your blog.
        'items_wrap'      => '<ul id="nav_menu">%3$s</ul>',
            )
        );
        ?>
        </div>
        <?php if ($options->get($themeslug.'_hide_search') != "0"):?>
        <div class="three columns">
            <?php get_search_form(); ?>
        </div>
        <?php endif;?>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
 <?php
}

/**
* End
*/
```

And the CSS:

```
    /#nav{position:relative;z-index:2000}
#nav .parent > a, #nav .parent > a:hover{background-image:url(../images/arrow.png);background-position:right;background-repeat:no-repeat}
#nav ul ul .parent > a, #nav ul ul .parent:hover > a:hover, #nav ul ul li:hover ul .parent > a, #nav ul ul li:hover ul .parent > a:hover{background-image:url(../images/arrow-right.png);background-position:right;background-repeat:no-repeat}
#nav ul, #nav ul li{display:inline;list-style:none;padding:0;margin:0}
#nav ul li a{display:inline-block;font-family:'Lucida Grande',Helvetica,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;font-size:14px;color:#fff;line-height:36px;text-decoration:none;text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #333;padding:0 15px;margin-left:-4px;border-right:#006747 1px solid}
#nav ul li a:hover{box-shadow:inner 0 0 5px #000;-moz-box-shadow:inset 0 0 5px #000;-webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 0 5px#000;background:#004f36}
#nav .current-menu-item a{color:#FFF;}
#nav .current-menu-item .sub-menu a{color:#fff;text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #333}
#nav .menu > li:first-child a:hover{border-radius:0}
#nav .menu .sub-menu li a:hover{border-radius:0}
#nav ul li{position:relative}
#nav li ul{display:none;position:absolute;top:27px;left:7px}
#nav li ul a{background:#009051}
#nav ul ul li:hover ul, #nav ul ul ul li:hover ul{left:0;margin:-37px 0 11px 180px}
#nav ul li:hover ul{display:inline-block}
#nav ul ul, #nav ul li:hover ul ul, #nav ul ul li:hover ul ul{display:none}
#nav ul li:hover ul, #nav ul ul li:hover ul, #nav ul ul ul li:hover ul{display:block}
#nav ul li:hover ul li a, #nav ul ul li:hover ul li a, #nav ul ul ul li:hover ul li a{border:#006747 1px solid;margin:-1px 0 0 -11px}
#nav ul li:hover ul li a{width:150px;padding:0 14px}
#nav ul ul li:hover ul li a{width:150px;padding:0 14px;background-color:#888}
#nav ul ul ul li:hover ul li a{width:150px;padding:0 14px;background-color:#aaa}
#nav .children {z-index: 4000;}
```

Hope someone can help, I've not done work on this in a while and I'm having trouble from the outset.

Ref: http://burytest.tk

---

Negative removed from

```
#nav ul li:hover ul li a, #nav ul ul li:hover ul li a, #nav ul ul ul li:hover ul li a{border:#006747 1px solid;margin:-1px 0 0 0}
```

Positive removed from

```
#nav ul ul li:hover ul, #nav ul ul ul li:hover ul{left:0;margin:-37px 0 0 180px}
```

Seemed to do the job.

Also, in  relation to my markup, the only problem is that when creating it I added a doctype tag onto the separate pages, afterwards I found it easier adding it to the header.

The fact that it's wordpress and a lot of the plugins I've added probably have some kind of errors in them doesn't help either!

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

At first, you should remove those errors.
http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fburytest.tk%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

You can fix the ghosting issue by removing your negative margin and adding negative positioning.

Change this lines in style.css:

```
Line #156: #nav li ul{display:none;position:absolute;top:27px;left:-4px}
Line #162: #nav ul li:hover ul li a, #nav ul ul li:hover ul li a, #nav ul ul ul li:hover ul li a{border:#006747 1px solid;margin:-1px 0 0 0}
```

It's just a fast and dirty fix.

Comment: I've ran it through the validator before, the errors that end up cropping up have never affected anything, that was suggested the last time there was a problem, but after hours of fixing errors I found the error within the code, there was simply a few things wrong it, nothing to do with validator errors.

I'll start on the errors but could I possibly have a second opinion on what needs to be changed?

Comment: The Validator is clearly still in progress for html5, it's giving me a stray end tag error, I've searched through many website's and found that this is a common problem.

As I cannot get past this error on the validator I will need a different approach.

Comment: You have a double doctype tag on line #1 and #142 and you are starting scripts and styles without starting html or head at first. I have edited my answer but I think it's an ugly fix. You have to clean up your markup.